# Distribution/moments of transformed normally distributed random vector

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, random-matrices

Let $\varepsilon \sim N\left ( 0,I_{k} \right )$, consider the following function of $\varepsilon$,

$y=\left ( A+B\varepsilon \varepsilon {}'B{}' \right )^{^{\frac{1}{2}}}\varepsilon $,

where $A$ is a positive semi-definite symmetric $k\times k$ matrix, $B$ is a $k\times k$ matrix.
I want to find the distribution or the approximate distribution of $y$, or some moments of $y$, such as $E\left ( yy{}' \right )$, $E\left ( yy{}'\otimes  yy{}' \right )$.

Answer (score 4):

let me calculate $\mathbb{E}[y^\top y]=\text{tr}\,\mathbb{E}[yy^\top]$ (using [Isserlis theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isserlis%27_theorem)):

$$\mathbb{E}[y^\top y]=\sum_{ij}\mathbb{E}\bigl[A_{ij}\epsilon_j\epsilon_i\bigr]+\sum_{ijkl}\mathbb{E}\bigl[B_{ij} \epsilon_j \epsilon_l B_{kl} \epsilon_k\epsilon_i\bigr]$$
$$\qquad=\sum_{ij}A_{ij}\delta_{ij}+\sum_{ijkl}B_{ij}B_{kl}(\delta_{jl}\delta_{ki}+\delta_{ji}\delta_{lk}+\delta_{jk}\delta_{li})$$
$$\qquad=\text{tr}\,A+(\text{tr}\,B)^2+\text{tr}\,B^2+\text{tr}\,BB^\top.$$